# docker-compose command not found in jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to connect to bitbucket using Jenkins and build an image using docker-compose and push the image built to docker-hub. I am able to connect to the bitbucket using Jenkins pipeline. However, I am running into a docker-compose error in Jenkins when building the pipeline.

I have tried including the full path of the docker-compose in my pipeline, but I am still getting the same error. Also tried, putting it in a path variable, which also resulted in the same error. Below is the code. The docker-compose file is in the exact path as the bitbucket clone in the step 'Cloning Git'. Any help is appreciated, Thank you!

```
pipeline {
  environment {
        registry = "xxxx/xxx"
        registryCredential = 'xxxxx'

        dockerImage = ''
  }
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
      steps {
        git branch: 'dev',
        credentialsId: 'xxxx',
        url: 'xxxx'
      }
    }
    stage('Printing content') {
      steps {
        sh 'pwd; ls -l;'
      }
    }
    stage('Building Image') {
      steps {
        sh './usr/bin/docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build'
      }
    }



    }

  }
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/docker-compose` not `./usr/bin/docker-compose`.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Solved the issue by directly installing Jenkins on the host. Earlier I was having docker-compose on my host and Jenkins was running in a container. For some reason, docker-compose command was not accessible. When I installed Jenkins directly on the host, it solved the issue. Though that is not what I exactly wanted, it served my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

i solve the issue by changing the agent pipline from agent { docker { image 'python:3.6' args '-u 0:0'   }   } to agent any

Comment: I appears that OP already has that in their script.